# Data Exchange Framework is returning missing plugin error when running pipeline batch

Tags: data-exchange-framework

I am working on Sitecore Data Exchange Framework 1.4.1 with Sitecore 8.2 Update 1 wherein I have to read data from XML web service and write to Sitecore Content editor. I have created the Data exchange framework provider for reading the data following the DEF documentation. But when i run the pipeline batch finally, I'm getting the following error:

> 7/18/2018 7:52:25 AM  ERROR   Pipeline context is missing at least one
>   required plugin. (pipeline: Read LMS Class Details from XML Data
>   Pipeline, pipeline step: Iterate Rows from XML Data and Run Pipelines
>   Pipeline Step, missing plugins:
>   Sitecore.DataExchange.Plugins.IterableDataSettings) 7/18/2018 7:52:25
>   AM    ERROR   Pipeline step will be skipped because the processor cannot
>   processes the pipeline step. (pipeline: Read LMS Class Details from
>   XML Data Pipeline, pipeline step: Iterate Rows from XML Data and Run
>   Pipelines Pipeline Step, pipeline step processor:
>   Sitecore.DataExchange.Processors.PipelineSteps.IterateAndRunPipelinesStepProcessor)

I have also kept breakpoint in my code and trying to debug the code. But the debugger is not hitting the AddPlugins method. Not sure what I'm missing. Anybody have an idea on what could be the issue?

Thanks
Vijayarajan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that `Iterate Rows from XML Data` pipeline step processor is trying to find `IterableDataSettings` plugin in the pipeline context and cannot find it.

`IterateAndRunPipelinesStepProcessor` processor is designed in order to loop through the collection and run pipeline(s) for a single object.

How to fix?

Verify if **before** `Iterate Rows from XML Data` pipeline step there is a pipeline step with assigned pipeline step processor that create new `IterableDataSettings` plugin and adds them to pipeline context plugin's collection.

The pipeline step should implement something like this:

```
IEnumarable data = ReadXMLRows();
IterableDataSettings  iterableDataSettings = new IterableDataSettings(data)
context.Plugins.Add(iterableDataSettings);
```

Read LMS Class Details from XML Data Pipeline

- Read Xml Rows Pipeline Step (missed pipeline step)
- Iterate Rows from XML Data and Run Pipelines Pipeline Step

Comment: Thanks for your reply Vlad. I am still not sure what created the issue. But I removed the both the pipeline steps one by one in the pipeline batch list and added once again and saved it and ran the pipeline batch again. Now it works fine. :-)